# error in sending email in oracle 11g with oracle linux 5.9

Tags: linux, oracle11g

my os is oracle linux 5.9.i have a procedure( in oracle11g )that sends email with utl_smtp package
this is my procedure

```
    declare
    l_mail_con 
     utl_smtp.connection;
    begin
    l_mail_con:=utl_smtp.open_connection('smtp.gmail.com',25);
    utl_smtp.EHLO(l_mail_con,'smtp.gmail.com');
    utl_smtp.command(l_mail_con,'STARTTLS');
    utl_smtp.command(l_mail_con,'AUTH','LOGIN');
    utl_smtp.command(l_mail_con,utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('myemail@gmail.com')));
    utl_smtp.command(l_mail_con,utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('mypass')));

    utl_smtp.mail(l_mail_con,'mymail@gmail.com');
    utl_smtp.rcpt(l_mail_con,'receivermail.com');
    utl_smtp.data(l_mail_con,'hi saeideh'||utl_tcp.crlf||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.quit(l_mail_con);

    end;

    /
```

and this is my error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 54
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 138
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 219
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

and this is telnet output

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25

Trying 173.194.65.109...

Connected to smtp.gmail.com (173.194.65.109).

Escape character is '^]'.

220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP fa13sm2443360wid.17 - gsmtp

ehlo Page on gmail.com

smtp.gmail.com at your service, [188.158.207.128]

250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME

250-STARTTLS

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-CHUNKING

250 SMTPUTF8

starttls
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

auth login

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

how can i solve this error?
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not enabled `ACL (access control list)`:

1. Create an ACL with one database user in Oracle database

   ```
   BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL (
   acl => 'smtp-gate-permissions.xml',
   description => 'Permissions for smtp gate',
   principal => 'SCOTT',
   is_grant => TRUE,
   privilege => 'connect'
   );
   COMMIT;
   END;
   ```
2. Assign an ACL to one or more network hosts

   ```
   BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL (
   acl => 'smtp-gate-permissions.xml',
   host => '<smtp_server>',
   lower_port => 25,
   upper_port => null);
   COMMIT;
   END;
   ```
3. Confirmation

   ```
   SELECT host, lower_port, upper_port, acl
   FROM   dba_network_acls;

   SELECT acl,
   principal,
   privilege,
   is_grant,
   TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') AS start_date,
   TO_CHAR(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS end_date
   FROM   dba_network_acl_privileges
   ```